# SharePoint 404 Error When Calling workflow.asmx Web Service

Tags: ajax, web-services, sharepoint, workflow

With the following code I receive a 404 (Not Found) error. I can see that the workflow.asmx URL is correct and I can access it through a browser. I've used similar code in the past on other projects.

```
function StartExpenseReportToPdfWorkflow(itemId) {
    var targetUrl = "../_vti_bin/workflow.asmx";
    var listName = "Expense Reports";
    var itemUrl = getUrlForListItemId(listName, itemId);
    var soapEnv = [];
    soapEnv.push("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    soapEnv.push("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"");
    soapEnv.push(" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"");
    soapEnv.push(" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
    soapEnv.push("<soap:Body>");
    soapEnv.push("<StartWorkflow xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/workflow/\">");
    soapEnv.push("<item>" + itemUrl + "</item>");
    soapEnv.push("<templateId>" + expenseReportWorkflowTemplateId + "</templateId>");
    soapEnv.push("<workflowParameters><data>");
    soapEnv.push("</data></workflowParameters>");
    soapEnv.push("</StartWorkflow>");
    soapEnv.push("</soap:Body>");
    soapEnv.push("</soap:Envelope>");
    //get web service url:
    var spsdiscoUrl = $("head link[rel='alternate']:eq(0)").attr("href");
    var spWSUrlPrefix = spsdiscoUrl.substr(0, spsdiscoUrl.length - 13);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: targetUrl, //spWSUrlPrefix + "workflow.asmx",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/workflow/StartWorkflow");
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv.join(""),
        complete: function (msg) {
            if (msg.status === 200) { } else {
                //Failure
                jsUtil.throwError("Well, this is awkward. Something went wrong and we're really sorry. " + msg.statusText, "Error calling Published Workflow: " + msg.statusText);
            }
        },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    });
}

function getUrlForListItemId(listName, itemId) {
    var domain = document.domain;
    var spsdiscoUrl = $("head link[rel='alternate']:eq(0)").attr("href");
    var webPrefix = spsdiscoUrl.substr(0, spsdiscoUrl.length - 22);
    return window.location.protocol + "//" + domain + webPrefix + "Lists/" + listName + "/" + itemId + "_.000";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by an incorrect list name. The correct name is "ExpenseReports" without the space. The 401 error led me to believe that there was a problem accessing the workflow.asmx web service itself. After several hours of checking and rechecking, I finally spotted the error.